# Performing side step operation in reactive programming

Tags: kotlin, error-handling, reactive-programming, project-reactor, flatmap

```
  fun test1(): Mono<ResponseFromTest2> {
        return test2()
            .flatMap { responseFromTest2 ->
               // do some operation
               Mono.just(responseFromTest2) 
             }
            .doOnNext {
                publishMetrics()
            }
    }
```

I am trying to find an operator where in I can perform a side-step operation. I was considering using the `doOnNext` operator. One issue here is if publishMetrics() function throws any exception, the Mono emitted from the flatMap won't be propagated but the error will be propagated instead. This seems like an unnecessary work from a side-step operation. One way is to handle the exception through `try-catch` block. But I wanted to know if there is any such operator which would handle the exception implicitly without us writing a `try-catch` block or any `onErrorResume`. To simplify with respect to this example: Is there any operator that can perform a side-step operation, if any exception thrown by the side-step operation won't be propagated downstream and the initial `Mono` emitted from the `flatMap` will instead be passed downstream.

Comment: What is a "side-step operation"?

Comment: Let's say the flatMap is producing a flux, then for each item we publish a log or a metric for that item. It's called side-step cause we're not actually modifying the emitted item and publishing any new item. Hence, instead of another Map or flatMap we can use doOnNext

Comment: I see, so what do you want to do if `publishMetrics` throws an exception? Do you want to completely ignore the exception?

Comment: Yes, ignore the exception and just emit the Mono as it is. I can achieve this through a try-catch block within the "side-step" `publishMetrics` operation but wanted to know if there is any operator in project reactor that implicitly does this

Comment: No, i doubt such operator exists, it doesn't make sense to lose an Exception. `try/catch` is the way